# Run a function multiple times with different arguments each run

Tags: r

I am trying to run a function multiple times using different arguments for each run. The arguments are called by a sub function and the output of the sub function is then used in the main function. I have been trying to do it using `mapply` but am not having any luck..

Pseudo-code of what I am trying to do:

Create a df of 8 different possible argument combinations to use in the function:

```
a <- 1:2
b <- 1:2
c <- 1:2
my.args <- expand.grid(a = a, b = b, c = c)

head(my.args)
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
3 1 2 1
4 2 2 1
5 1 1 2
```

Create the function

```
my.func <- function(a,b,c) {
    my.sub.func <- function(bits = c(0,1,2), times = 1) {
    sample(bits, times, prob = c(a,b,c), replace = TRUE)
    }
 #..... do a bunch of stuff using my.sub.func()

}
```

run the function using each each row of `my.args` as the input arguments

```
mapply (my.func, a = my.args[,1], b = my.args[,2], c = my.args[,3])
```

This does not work, I think the issue has something to do with the structure of `prob = c(a,b,c)` in `my.sub.func()`

Comment: You need to actually call `my.sub.func`

Comment: I think you want something like `do.call(mapply, c(function(a, b, c){sample(0:2, 1, prob = c(a, b, c))}, my.args))`

Comment: It's really equivalent to a typo (as alistaire identified). Perhaps call it a 'thinko'?

Comment: @alistaire @42-  hmm maybe I need to rethink how I have written my function/do some reading, I want to run the `my.sub.func` inside the larger `my.func` as the result of `my.sub.func` is then used for a bunch of other calculations inside `my.func`. Maybe I am better to use `do.call` as alistaire suggests and then have `my.func` reference the resulting vector of `do.call`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @alistaire I got it working, as stated I needed to actually call `my.sub.func` along with adding a variable to the `my.func` function which stores each iteration's argument combination.

```
a <- 1:2
b <- 1:2
c <- 1:2
my.args <- expand.grid(a = a, b = b, c = c)

my.func <- function(a,b,c) {

  ## add a variable to store argument values in
  triplet <- c(a, b, c)

  my.sub.func <- function(bits = c(0,1,2), times = 1) {
    sample(bits, times, prob = triplet, replace = TRUE)
  }

  ## actually call the function
  my.sub.func()

  #..... do a bunch of stuff using my.sub.func() here
}

mapply (my.func, my.args[,1], my.args[,2], my.args[,3])
```

As it currently stands this produces the same output as `do.call(mapply, c(function(a, b, c){sample(0:2, 1, prob = c(a, b, c))}, my.args))` but I can now add other calculations to `my.func` (i.e. `#..... do a bunch of other stuff here`) which will be included in `mapply`.